# How to list a simple private variable from outside a construct (closure)?

Tags: javascript, variables, constructor, closures, private

Is there any way to list a private variable outside the context of the constructor function?

E.g:

```
function Person() {
  let globalId = 10;
  this.listGlobalId = function() {
    return globalId;
  }
};

let alan = new Person;
```

Now we'll have after a console.log of alan something like: `"Person { listGlobalId: [Function] }"`

**Is there any way to recover the "globalId" from object alan?**

Comment: `console.log(alan.listGlobalId())` will do it. Or do you mean some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make private a property of a class (only accesible from inside) you can declare the property name followed by #. Then you can access your private variable with a getter.

```js
class Person {
  #globalId;
  
  constructor(name, globalId){
    this.name = name;
    this.#globalId = globalId;
  }
  
  get getGlobalId(){
    return this.#globalId;
  }
};

let alan = new Person('alan', 3);

console.log(alan.getGlobalId);    // 3
//console.log(alan.#globalId);    // Error
```

If you are looking for a method only accesible from the class, you can use a static method:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this._name = name;
  }
  static generateName() {       // You can call it directly from the class, but not from an instance of the class.
    const names = ['Angel', 'Pedro', 'Luis', 'Mario', 'Julio'];
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
    return names[randomNumber];
  }
} 
console.log(Person.generateName());  // Returns a random name.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `this.#privateVariables` is the main way, but `#` private variables don't have much support (~67% at time of writing). I don't like to transpile if I can avoid it, so here's some solutions that have a lot of browser support.

```js
// Code to match your example
function Person() {
  let globalId = 10;
  this.listGlobalId = function() {
    return globalId;
  }
  
  // Kind of like a getter
  this.iifeGlobalId = (function() {
    return globalId;
  })();
};

let alan = new Person;

console.log('Person getter ', alan.iifeGlobalId);
console.log('Person Object ', alan);

// Class Based solutions

class Adult {
  constructor() {
    let globalId = 10;
    this.globalId = 10;
  }
  
  // Kind of like #globalId
  // Except that __globalId will
  // still be listed if you log the
  // class
  set globalId(num) {
    if (!this.__globalId) this.__globalId = num;
  }
  
  get globalId() {
    return this.__globalId;
  }
}

const adultAlan = new Adult;

console.log('Adult pseudo private properties ', adultAlan.globalId)
console.log('Adult __globalId still shows up ', { adultAlan })

const privateMap = new Map();

class PrivateAdult {
  constructor() {
    privateMap.set(this, {
      globalId: 10,
      otherSecret: 'banana bread'
    });
  }
  
  get globalId() {
    const instance = privateMap.get(this);
    return instance.globalId;
  }
}

/**
  This PrivateAdult class only works if you export the
  class from a module but keep the privateMap variable
  inside the original module. 
**/

const privateAlan = new PrivateAdult;

console.log('PrivateAdult ', privateAlan.globalId);
console.log('PrivateAdult keeps everything neat :) ', { privateAlan });
console.log('Get information from privateMap using the created privateAlan class ', privateMap.get(privateAlan));
```

The last one assumes support for [`type="module"`](https://caniuse.com/?search=type%20module) (92.5% of browsers). It also has fallback support using `type="nomodule"`.